# Programmatically/Manually create a MKPlacemark/CLPlacemark

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

**Problem**

I have a set of placemark information (country, city, etc) and a Lat/Lon pair.  I would like to use this to create an MKPlacemark object.

---

**Discussion**

It appears that this class can only be created by

```
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary
```

whose docs state states

> You can create placemark objects manually for entities for which you already have address information, such as contacts in the Address Book. Creating a placemark object explicitly avoids the need to query the reverse geocoder object for the same information.

Perfect!  I have already reverse-geocoded and wish to avoid such a query.  What can I add to the dictionary?

> For a list of strings that you can use for the keys of this dictionary, see the “Address Property” constants in ABPerson Reference. All of the keys in should be at the top level of the dictionary.

Which shows relevant keys

```
const ABPropertyID kABPersonAddressProperty;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStreetKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCityKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStateKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressZIPKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCountryKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey;
```

This falls quite short of the base traits for an MKPlacemark:

> Accessing the Location Data

- location  property

> Accessing the Placemark Attributes

- name  property
- addressDictionary  property
- ISOcountryCode  property
- country  property
- postalCode  property
- administrativeArea  property
- subAdministrativeArea  property
- locality  property
- subLocality  property
- thoroughfare  property
- subThoroughfare  property
- region  property

> Accessing Geographic Information

- inlandWater  property
- ocean  property

> Accessing Landmark Information

- areasOfInterest  property

Fortunately, the actual header file for MKPlacemark's superclass says something about the address dictionary:

```
// address dictionary properties

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name; // eg. Apple Inc.

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *thoroughfare; // street address, eg. 1 Infinite Loop

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subThoroughfare; // eg. 1

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *locality; // city, eg. Cupertino

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subLocality; // neighborhood, common name, eg. Mission District

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *administrativeArea; // state, eg. CA

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subAdministrativeArea; // county, eg. Santa Clara

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *postalCode; // zip code, eg. 95014

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *ISOcountryCode; // eg. US

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *country; // eg. United States

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *inlandWater; // eg. Lake Tahoe

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *ocean; // eg. Pacific Ocean

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *areasOfInterest; // eg. Golden Gate Park
```

So, I create a dictionary and then pass it like so:

```
return [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:aLocation.coordinate addressDictionary:addressDictionary] autorelease];
```

Unfortunately, after all that, introspection shows that the information did not stick:

```
NSLog(@"placemark %@ from %@", placemark, addressDictionary);
NSLog(@"has %@", placemark.thoroughfare);
```

Prints

```
2012-01-31 20:14:22.545 [15450:1403] placemark <+___,-___> +/- 0.00m from {
administrativeArea = __;
postalCode = _____;
subAdministrativeArea = ___;
subThoroughfare = __;
thoroughfare = "_____";
}
2012-01-31 20:14:22.545[15450:1403] has (null)
```

### *Conclusion*

So, I'm about at the end here.  Has anyone figured out how to create your own MKPlacemark?  Thanks.

Comment: Your addressDictionary looks empty.  What if you NSLog it before your return statement? (Fwiw, I generally don't alloc, init, autorelease and return all in the same statement.  It's easier to debug if you break them into separate statements.)

Comment: Look again at the debug output - the dictionary is definitely showing 5 values (I redacted the values).  How to get values into an MKPlacemark is the central problem.  Thank!

Comment: Ah, I see.  Did you also redact the placemark?  What does that look like in the debugger **before** you return it from the method?

Comment: Just the gps coordinates.  What is meaningful should be apparent: a placemark is created.  The dictionary has values.  The resulting placemark is empty.  Perhaps the dictionary needs special keys?  Or there is another means to create the placemark?

Comment: Wow, I was JUST trying to do the exact same thing and running into the same problem! In my case I have a BSKmlResult (courtesy of the excellent BSForwardGeocoder, as I still need to support iOS 4, otherwise I'd use CLGeocoder). I made a class extension on MKPlacemark and tried doing essentially the same thing, but to no avail. :(

Answer (score 4):

You can subclass `MKPlacemark`:

In **MyPlacemark.h**

```
@interface MyPlacemark : MKPlacemark

extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressThoroughfareKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubThoroughfareKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressLocalityKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubLocalityKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressAdministrativeAreaKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubAdministrativeAreaKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressPostalCodeKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryCodeKey;

@end
```

In **MyPlacemark.m**:

```
#import "MyPlacemark.h"

@implementation MyPlacemark

NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressThoroughfareKey = @"thoroughfare";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubThoroughfareKey = @"subThoroughfare";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressLocalityKey = @"locality";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubLocalityKey = @"subLocality";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressAdministrativeAreaKey = @"administrativeArea";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubAdministrativeAreaKey = @"subAdministrativeArea";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressPostalCodeKey = @"postalCode";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryKey = @"country";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryCodeKey = @"countryCode";

- (NSString *)thoroughfare
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressThoroughfareKey];
}

- (NSString *)subThoroughfare
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubThoroughfareKey];
}

- (NSString *)locality
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressLocalityKey];
}

- (NSString *)subLocality
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubLocalityKey];
}

- (NSString *)administrativeArea
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressAdministrativeAreaKey];
}

- (NSString *)subAdministrativeArea
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubAdministrativeAreaKey];
}

- (NSString *)postalCode
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressPostalCodeKey];
}

- (NSString *)country
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryKey];    
}

- (NSString *)countryCode
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryCodeKey];
}

@end
```

It looks ugly, but it's the only way so far that I've found to work.

Comment: Ugly, agreed, but if it's the only sane way ... whaddaya gonna do? In my case it MAY work fine as-is, depending on whether I'm really using BSKmlResult under the hood (from BSForwardGeocoder), so I will just turn my class extension into a subclass and call back to the superclass if BSKmlResult is not set in my subclass.